# Ruby Rails Time.change not working as I would expect...I have checked the docs!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, date, time

I have a form that contains one date element and 3 time elements.  This is because 3 time events will occur on one date, and I don't want the user to have to input that date 3 times.

On the server side, I would like to combine the one date with the 3 times to get 3 datetime objects.  I was thinking I could just do something like:

```
time_object.change(:day => date_object.day, :month => date_object.month, :year => date_object.year)
```

but this has not worked.  Here is a simple test I have written that I would expect to work:

```
  def before_validation
    logger.info("show_time = " + self.show_time.to_s)
    self.show_time.change(:year => 2012)
    self.show_time.change(:minute => 30)
    logger.info("show_time = " + self.show_time.to_s)
  end
```

The two print statements should be different, but they are the same. Does anyone know the best way to merge a Time and Date object?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to assign it. If you go into script/console:

```
>> t = Time.now
=> Thu Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2009
>> t.change(:year => 2012)
=> Mon Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2012
>> t
=> Thu Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2009
>> t = t.change(:year => 2012)
=> Mon Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2012
>> t
=> Mon Apr 09 21:03:25 +1000 2012
```

so maybe:

```
self.show_time = self.show_time.change(:year => 2012)
```

could work for you. I don't know how I feel about that solution, but it should work.

Comment: I was trying to change parts of a Time object with little luck. Looked at the rdocs for Time and couldn't find anything which would lead me to using the "change" method. Thanks for this answer, helped me much.

Comment: This is somebody from the year 2012... um... Hi, you called?

Answer (score 2):

Also note that to change the minute you use `:min` instead of `:minute`