# Rails - set the hour on datetime from within controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a form that includes a date-field associated with a datetime. The date is set by the user but the hour should always be 8pm UTC (20 on a 24-hour clock).

I tried setting it through my controller with

```
def create
    @rfq = Rfq.new(rfq_params)
    @rfq.owner = current_user.email
    @rfq.due.change(hour: 20)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @rfq.save
        format.html { redirect_to @rfq, notice: 'Rfq was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @rfq }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @rfq.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

But when I save it, it always comes out to 00:00:00 UTC

Thank you ahead of time for the response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be having the same issue as here:
[Ruby Rails Time.change not working as I would expect...I have checked the docs!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733661/ruby-rails-time-change-not-working-as-i-would-expect-i-have-checked-the-docs)

You are not assigning the change:

```
    @rfq.due = @rfq.due.change(hour: 20)
```